# Javascript/JQuery Callback confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a Modal which I show for confirmation:

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
             ... Body ...
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="btnCancel" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" id="btnOk" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code for showing the above Modal..

```
var M = {
 confirm: function(body, yes, no) {
    $('#btnCancel').on('click', function() {
       $('#btnCancel').off();
       $('#confirm-modal').modal('hide');
       if (no) {
            return no();
       }
    });
    $('#btnOk').on('click', function() {
      $('#btnOk').off(); 
      $('#modal').modal('hide');
      if (yes) {
         return yes();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

And here is how I am using it... (In any view for example)

```
M.confirm("Body", function(){
   // Function Body
})
```

Now, the problem is: If I call confirm, it shows the Modal. But if I click Cancel and than again call confirm and this time, I hit OK: the function (second param in the snippet above) is called twice. If I hit cancel 10 times, the function above is called 10 times.

Any idea why this is happening?

Thank You.

Comment: You are assigning event handlers every time you call `confirm()`. So the second time you call confirm, you are adding another set of handlers (not replacing the old ones). You should remove the event handlers from the `confirm()` function and just assign them once.

Comment: Consider using `.one()` https://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: `.on()` is additive... `.one()` is only once.

Comment: @Scott/Hive7/Jeremy Got it.. Thank you all..

Comment: @JeremyThille That's a bit misleading since you can add multiple listeners with one() but each only gets called once.  https://jsfiddle.net/oubm4vtx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call `confirm` you add an event handler to each of `btnCancel` and `btnOk`.

However, you only **remove** the effect handler on one of those buttons when **that** button is clicked.

So if you call `confirm`, then click `btnCancel`, then call `confirm` you'll have **two** event handlers on `btnOK`: One from the first call to `confirm` and once from the second.

When **either** button is clicked you need to remove **both** event handlers.

… or just add the event handlers when the document is loaded and don't touch them thereafter.